# converting hexadecimal string to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, string, hex

I wrote a program that converts a hexadecimal string into a byte array, eg `"2e65"` produces `[2,14,6,5]`.

Is there a way to do it with less lines of code or without using the ASCII table values.

```
public static byte[] stringToData( String dataString) {
    byte [] hexStringToByteArr = new byte[dataString.length()];
    for ( int i = 0; i < dataString.length(); i++) {
        char c = dataString.charAt(i);
        if ( c == 48 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 0;}
        if ( c == 49 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 1;}
        if ( c == 50 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 2;}
        if ( c == 51 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 3;}
        if ( c == 52 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 4;}
        if ( c == 53 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 5;}
        if ( c == 54 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 6;}
        if ( c == 55 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 7;}
        if ( c == 56 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 8;}
        if ( c == 57 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 9;}
        if ( c == 97 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 10;}
        if ( c == 98 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 11;}
        if ( c == 99 ) { hexStringToByteArr[i] = 12;}
        if ( c == 100 ) {hexStringToByteArr[i] = 13;}
        if ( c == 101 ) {hexStringToByteArr[i] = 14;}
        if ( c == 102 ) {hexStringToByteArr[i] = 15;}
    }
    return hexStringToByteArr;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    String pracString = "2e65";    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringToData(pracString)));
}
```

Comment: `2e65` should be two bytes, not four.

Comment: You can use `hexStringToByteArr[i]=Character.digit(c,16);` instead of all the if statements.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you tell me why I need two instead of four? i did what said with the dividing by 2 but it causes my program to have an error. Also I do not understand logically, if my string has 4 values, would I not need the same amount of indexes in my byte array to fit them in?

Comment: One byte is 2 hex digits, if it were one digit it would be constrained to sixteen values (hence hex).

Comment: Incase I didnt write my question correctly. My code is working as intended with the output. I need every single hexadecimal character to be displayed in its decimal form in a byte array

Comment: Notes: `char` is an integral type in Java;`48 == '0'`, `49 == '1'`, ... `97 == 'a'`... // to convert a decimal digit (`char ch`) to `int` just do `ch - '0'` (or `ch - 48`, but first is easier to read/understand) - similar for letters `a`-`f` (`ch - 'a' + 10` - need to add 10 since `'a'` has value 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"2e65"` in hexadecimal represents two bytes (`2e`, which corresponds to `46` in decimal, and `65`, which corresponds to `101` in decimal). To get a `byte[]` containing two bytes, you can utilize `BigInteger`:

```
String hex = "2e65";
byte[] b = new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

The output of the above snippet is:

```
[46, 101]
```

---

If, instead, you want to convert each of the four hexadecimal digits to a `byte` and store them in a `byte[]`, then you can use [`Character#digit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,int)) while iterating over each `char` in the `String`:

```
String hex = "2e65";
byte[] b = new byte[hex.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = (byte) Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

The output of the above snippet is:

```
[2, 14, 6, 5]
```

Comment: The second output is what I was asking for. Thanks for providing both.

Answer (score 0):

To convert hex string to byte array, you need to first get the length of the given string and include it while creating a new byte array.

```
string str = "2e65";
byte[] val = new byte[str.length() / 2];
```

Now, take a for loop until the length of the byte array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
   int index = i * 2;
   int j = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
   val[i] = (byte) j;
}
```

So, since byte arrays must be half the length, change this line

```
byte[] hexStringToByteArr = new byte[dataString.length()];
```

to this:

```
byte[] hexStringToByteArr = new byte[dataString.length() / 2];
```

Comment: why must byte arrays be half the length? wouldnt I need a byte array of 4 indexes since i have 4 values? If i include byte[] hexStringToByteArr = new byte[dataString.length() / 2]; i get an out of bounds of array error

Comment: @wetmoney You get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error because your code tries to access indexes of the byte array that are beyond half the string length. Use my code instead (so the `for` loop included) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your big block o' ifs can be replaced with:

```
hexStringToByteArr[i] = c < 58 ? c - 48 : c - 87;
```